# Эффект-прозрачности

Tags: html, css, эффекты, прозрачность

Не могу никак отстилизовать последнего кота.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через опасити не получается т.к. бек станет прозрачным.
Так вот задача состоит в том что-бы оставить бек, сделать данный эффект.

Comment: Вы верстаете, рисуете? Обновите теги что ли, а то не понятно что вам именно нужно.

Comment: у вас вопрос про фотошоп или про что?

Comment: в любом случае, белую подложку сделайте, хоть в фш хоть в верстке,  не?

Comment: Верстаю. И ничего не получается

Comment: и `{opacity:0.5}` не помогает?)

Comment: А что вы верстаете? Как верстаете? Можно код глянуть?

Comment: opacity:0.5 просветит бек ,а нужно оставить бек

Comment: https://rusatov.github.io/Cat_Food/dist/  скопируй вёрстку - надоел этот вопрос ...сто раз был он уже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно расположить сверху белый блок и ему сделать `background-color:white; opacity:0.5;` или `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`

```css
div.masked {
  background: no-repeat url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif?s=32&g=1), wheat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.masked:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.masked:hover:before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="masked">hover</div>
<div class="masked">on</div>
<div class="masked">me</div>
```

Comment: https://rusatov.github.io/Cat_Food/dist/  за восемь лет этот вопрос вылазил раз так 30 наверно ...

Comment: @MaximLensky неплохо =) даже готовый сайт имеется

Answer (score 1):

Все что нужно это обернуть ваш полупрозрачный див в еще один, где уже будет применяться `background`. Тем самым `opacity` применяется к дочернему элементу, родительский не меняется и не просвечивает

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.parent {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}

.child {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #009688;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Еще раз говорю при опасити нужно будет менять цвет текста,цвет круга. Ибо текст будет прозрачным и черным ,а это я считаю не выход ,плюс не желательно оборачивать другим блоком так как это компонент vue.

Comment: Ну и? В чем проблема-то? У вас на скрине становится прозрачным все, кроме фона. В моем случае, все что вы поместите в `child`, будет становиться прозрачным, при этом фон не будет меняться

Comment: @user20477 _другим блоком так как это компонент vue_ обернуть карточку в блок сделав его родительским, в чем проблема?